# Play Soundcloud Audio Streams with Jplayer

Tags: jquery, soundcloud, jplayer

Hey i want to be able to play public soundcloud stream with my jplayer.
i thought of using soundclouds own api method, so i registered a app and tried to use

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/trackid/stream?client_id=client_id
```

this works in the browser when i visit the link but in my current code i need a link with the ending .mp3 to play the audio. since soundloud is using a 302 redirect to the mp3 url, it isnt working.

current code for grabbing the audio url

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    if (getCookie("volume")=="") {
        player_volume=0.8;
        setCookie("volume",0.8,"365")
    }
    else {
        player_volume=getCookie("volume")
    }

    $("#sound-player").jPlayer({ready:function(a) {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia",{})},cssSelectorAncestor:"#sound-container",swfPath:"themes/sound/js",supplied:"mp3",wmode:"window",volume:player_volume,smoothPlayBar:true,keyEnabled:true})
    });

    function playSong(c,e) {

        if (/Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            window.location=""+c;
            return false
        }

        $(".current-song").removeClass("current-song");
        $(".current-play").show();$(".current-play").removeClass("current-play");
        $(".current-seek").html($("#sound_ghost_player").html());
        $(".current-seek").removeClass("current-seek");

        var b=c.replace(".","\\.");

        $("#track"+e).addClass("current-song");
        $("#play"+e).addClass("current-play");
        $(".current-play").hide();

        if ($("#song-name"+e).html().length>25) {
            var d=$("#song-name"+e).html().substr(0,25)+"..."
        }
        else {
            var d=$("#song-name"+e).html()
        }

        $("#sw-song-name").html(d);
        $(".jp-audio .jp-time-holder").show();
        $("#sound-player").jPlayer("destroy");
        $("#song-controls"+e).html($("#seek-bar-song").html());
        $("#song-controls"+e).addClass("current-seek");
        $("#track"+e+" .jp-play , #track"+e+" .jp-pause").css({"margin-top":"-"+$(".song-top","#track"+e).outerHeight()+"px"});

        var a=getExtension(c);
        prevnext();

        $("#sound-player").jPlayer({ready:function(f) {
            if (a=="mp3") {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3:"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/"+c}).jPlayer("play")
            }
            else {
                if (a=="m4a") { 
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {m4a:"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/"+c}).jPlayer("play")
                }
            }
        }, cssSelectorAncestor:"#sound-container",ended: function() {
           $.ajax({
               type:"POST",
               url:"",
               data:"id="+e,
               cache:false,
               success:function(f){}
           });

           if ($("#repeat-song").html()==0) {
               $(".current-seek").html($("#sound_ghost_player").html());
               $(".current-play").show();
               nextSong(e)
           }
       },
       errorAlerts:true,
       swfPath:"themes/sound/js/",
       supplied:a,
       wmode:"window",
       volume:getCookie("volume"),
       smoothPlayBar:true,
       solution:"html, flash",
       keyEnabled:true
   })
}
```

i hope someone can help me out